# Why isn't main defined `main(std::vector<std::string> args)`?

Tags: c++, vector, coding-style, command-line-arguments, idioms

This question is only half tongue-in-cheek. I sometimes dream of a world without naked arrays or c strings.

If you're using c++, shouldn't the preferred definition of main be something like:

```
int main(std::vector<std::string> args)
```

?

There are already multiple definitions of `main` to choose from, why isn't there a version that is in the spirit of C++?

Comment: Implementations are free to offer other signatures for main provided they all return an int. So a better quetion would probably be why don't they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A concern that keeps coming back to my mind is that once you allow complex types, you end up with the risk of exceptions being thrown in the type's constructor.  And, as the language is currently designed, there's absolutely no way for such an exception to be caught.  If it were decided that such exceptions should be caught, then that would require considerably more work, both for the committee and compiler writers, making it all somewhat more troublesome than simply saying "allow `std::vector<std::string>>`".

There might be other issues as well.  The whole "incompatible with runtimes" seems like something of a red herring to me, given that you can provide basically the same functionality now with macros. But something like this is rather more involved.

Comment: Late answer, but I think it's the best. The real issue isn't compatibility with c or includes; it's the possibility of exceptions.

Comment: There is basically no more of a chance of an exception being thrown by an std::vector construction than by the construction of an array of string pointers and the null-terminated strings they point to.

Answer (score 11):

Because C++ was designed to be (almost) backwards compatible with C code.

There are cases where C code will break in a C++ compiler, but they're fairly rare, and there's generally a good reason for why this breakage is required.

But changing the signature of main, while convenient for us, isn't *necessary*. For someone porting code from C, it'd just be another thing you had to change, for no particular gain.

Another reason is that `std::vector` is a library, not a part of the core language. And so, you'd have to `#include <vector>` in *every* C++ program.

And of course, in its early years, C++ didn't *have* a vector. So when the vector was added to the language, sure, they *could* have changed the signature of `main`, but then they'd break not just C code, but also every existing C++ program.

Is it worth it?

Comment: We already have multiple definitions of `main` to pick from, why not add a c++ish version?

Comment: True, that could be done. But is it really worth the bother? You can just make the first line of your program `std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv+argc)`. The standard committee prefers only adding new things to the language if it offers *significant* advantages over a library approach.

Comment: Is it because to compile STL itself, one would require the standard library which in turn calls main?

Comment: @chubsdad: The standard library doesn't call `main`.

Comment: Inverse, notice that the multiple versions of `main` are all compatible with each other using the C calling convention. If an RTL calls `main(argc, argv, envp)`, but the function you've provided is just `main(int, char*[])`, the extra third parameter is safely ignored. An RTL can be written to always call a single version of `main` without regard for which version you provided. But `main(vector<string>)` is incompatible with other versions, so the RTL (already compiled, in a separate .o file) would need to know what you provided in your source code.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: I see your point, but the `wmain`'s definitely aren't compatible with `main`'s

Comment: @Inverse: and `wmain`isn't a part of standard C++ either. :) It is a Microsoft extension.

Answer (score 11):

There's another reason besides compatibility with C. In C++, **the standard library is meant to be entirely optional**. There's nothing about the C++ language itself that forces you to use things from the standard library like `std::string` and `std::vector`, and that is entirely by design. In fact, it is by design that you should be able to use some parts of the standard library without having to use others (although this has led to some generally annoying things like `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` operating on `const char*` C-style strings rather than on `std::string` objects).

The theory is that you are supposed to be able to take the C++ language and use whatever library of objects, containers, etc, that you want with it, be it the standard library or some proprietary library (e.g. Qt, MFC), or something that you created yourself. Defining `main` to accept an argument composed of types defined in the standard library defeats this design goal.

Comment: Except there are still things like std::type_info which are used by non-std:: language features.

Comment: But OP was asking about an _option_ to have `main()` defined this way. If this were possible you could still have your C-style `main()` and no standard library.

Answer (score 5):

Because it will force you to include `<vector>` and `<string>`.

Comment: Moreover, it will force you to use the same implementation of `<vector>` and `<string>` as the runtime library.

Comment: @Mike: But you don't neccessarily need to enter `main` from the runtime library. If the compiler generated a secret function that the runtime library would find that converted from the C arguments to the C++ types of your choice and then called the actual `main`, there shouldn't be a conflict. Unless I'm missing something, it would be a completely transparent change.

Comment: However, you already have the option of at least 2 variants of `main()`.  Adding a C++ specific one doesn't necessarily mean you'd be forced to use it (the existing options could remain as options). This might well complicate the machinery that the compiler/linker would need to support calling the right `main()` correctly, but it's not impossible. I'm not saying it would necessarily be worth the cost & complications - just that it's not impossible.

Comment: You could even go one step further and the compiler could allow any single argument, provided it can be constructed from a pair of bidirectional iterators. `int main(T args); int _Main(argc, argv) { return main(T(argv, argv + argc); }`

Comment: To summarize @MichaelBurr 's comment: No, it won't force you to include that. It would be an _option_.

Answer (score 4):

Like @jalf, I sometimes find myself writing

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv+argc);
```

But yes, like everyone said, `main` has to be C-compatible. I see it as an interface to the OS runtime, which is (at least int the systems I use) is written in C.

Although some development environment encourage replacements such as `wmain` or `_tmain`. You could write your own compiler/IDE, which would encourage the use of `int vmain(const std::vector<std::string>& args)`.

Comment: The runtime already has to know something about C++, to create and destroy static objects and handle uncaught exceptions. So it wouldn't be a huge leap to allow C++-specific variants of `main`; the only real objection to this one is that you'd have to standardise the implementation of `vector` and `string`.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: I guess you're right.. And then the question comes up why exactly std::basic_string<char> and why exactly std::vector. I would vote for `int main(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<CharT>>)`!

Comment: To take this one step farther - just have a `main()` snippet that you can have as a starting template in your editor/IDE that does nothing but `return cppMain( vector<string>(argv, argv+argc));` and use `cppMain()` as the 'customizable' starting point of your program.  I may actually start using this...

Answer (score 3):

Because C++ was in existence long before the C++ standard was, and built heavily on C. And, like the original ANSI C standard, codifying existing practice was an important part of it.

There's no point in changing something that works, especially if it will break a whole lot of existing code.

Even ISO C, which has been through quite a few iterations, still takes backwards compatibility *very* seriously.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, to remain compatable with C.  If we were to give up that, main() would be moved into a class.

Comment: why on Earth would you move main into a class? That doesn't even make sense to do. Java and C# only do it because non-member functions are disallowed by the language. But that doesn't make it an any less terrible design decision

Answer (score 2):

The multiple definitions of main() aren't really multiple definitions. There are three:

- `int main(void)` (C99)
- `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` (C99)
- `int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])` (POSIX, I think)

But in POSIX, you only *really* get the third. The fact that you can call a function with extra arguments is down to the C calling convention.

You *can't* have `extern "C" int main(std::vector<std::string> argv)` unless the memory layout happens to be magically compatible in a portable way. The runtime will call main() with the wrong arguments and fail. There's no easy way around this.

Instead, provided main() *wasn't* `extern "C"`, the runtime could try the various supported symbols in order until it found one. I imagine main() is `extern "C"` by default, and that you can't overload `extern "C"` functions.

For more fun, [void main(void)](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/readings/voidmain.960823.html).

Comment: That seems to be a VC++ feature. It's not obvious how it's implemented (it links to a different runtime, maybe?).

Answer (score 1):

I'll try explain in the best possible sentence.

C++ was designed to be backward compatible with C and `std::vector` was included in a library that only got included in C++.

Also, C++ and C programs were designed to run in shells or command lines (windows, linux, mac) and OS pass arguments to a program as an array of String. How would an OS really translate vectors?

That's the most reason I can think of, feel free to criticize it.