# Clever Way to Convert char** from/to vector<string>

Tags: c++, stdvector

What is the cleanest and cleverest way to convert from  `char**` to `vector<string>` and vice versa?

What about `char***` to `vector< vector<string> >` and vice versa?

Comment: Can you show an example of the "non-clever" way that you've established so far?

Comment: Loops and `new` and `std::copy`.

Comment: how do you know how many strings are in your `char **`? (for the second part especially)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3478272/242520

Comment: @barak How do you figure my "non-clever" way is relevant here? This question is simply meant to incite answers from seasoned programmers who can almost certainly do this better than I can.

Comment: Well, it's relevant because cleverness is something relative. And if you're asking for a clever way, then we need to be sure that it's more clever than your way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems pretty straightforward:

```
char **ptr;
size_t n_items;
// ...

vector<string> vec( ptr, ptr + n_items );
```